# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'React.PropTypes.Number') error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, expo

Just updated from `expo 21.0.0` to `22.0.0` and I am getting this error:

[image]

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "APP",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0",
    "jest-expo": "^22.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^22.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "3.3.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "1.0.9",
    "react-native-elements": "0.13.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "0.12.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "0.20.1",
    "react-native-tag-input": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Having hard time figuring out why updating messed up the app. Most likely it is a proptypes update thing, I am currently not using any proptypes in the app. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not using any PropTypes in the app, as I mentioned above

Comment: if you are not using PropTypes how come its in dependencies `"prop-types": "^15.6.0"`

Comment: Sorry about confusion, was just testing things out, It is not part of my package.json

Comment: It means some of your dependencies are not react-16 compatible in a sense they use `React.PropTypes` which is absent. As stack trace point out it is something required by `SideMenu.js`. grep for `React.PropTypes` in node_modules.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Hi, Thanks for the answer. If I am not mistaken Expo comes with react-native-side-menu and from searching I found that this is the reason for the bug https://image.prntscr.com/image/Kax8lf9-QO2Sog-4tt-lCw.png. As soon as I remove first 3 React.PropTypes.number I get this error https://image.prntscr.com/image/8HeQ5LY3T1KK2VR_dKSuBg.png

Comment: What do you mean by "grep for React.PropTypes in node_modules". How can it be fixed?

Comment: @nikasv I mean you could find which module is responsible. Not a fix but a candidate to update or file an issue.

Answer (score 6):

PropTypes is removed from react so you need to install prop-types and import it from that:

Install `prop-types`:

```
npm install prop-types --save
```

Import `PropTypes` from prop-type instead of import PropTypes from react:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: Don't forget to also change any references to `React.PropTypes` in your code to just `PropTypes`

Answer (score 2):

Check JS file for all module from npm module

```
"react-native-autocomplete-input": "3.3.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "1.0.9",
    "react-native-elements": "0.13.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "0.12.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "0.20.1",
    "react-native-tag-input": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27"
```

replace

```
import {PropTypes} from 'react';
```

with

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

in every file